# How to async stream big file through Spring MVC from external source?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlets, asynchronous, resttemplate

Calling all Spring Framework experts,

**Scenario**

> User **A** performs `GET` request to Spring Controller which makes another 
>   `GET` request to remote host to get a file which content is streamed (buffer 
>   byte copy) to initial user **A** as a response.

*PS: Spring Controller acts like a proxy*

**Using**

- Spring WebMVC 4.3.3.RELEASE
- Apache Tomcat 8.5.5

**Issue**

> Seems like there is no Servlet request thread available or something
>   else is blocked...

First user is able to initiate downloading of a file in all cases listed below.
Unfortunately, **Spring** stops to invoke controller download method until first download has been finished (but, sometimes, it invokes it after XX seconds of user's wait time). 
Tried approaches with

- `@Async` on a Service which contains `RestTemplate` approach -  throws `NullPointerException` during `byte copy operation` as response output buffer is `null` (`at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.doWrite(Http11OutputBuffer.java:561)`). Service - `download` method.
- `StreamingResponseBody` also doesn't resolve concurrent download issue even when wrapped in `@Async` on service level with `AsyncResult<StreamingResponseBody>` return. Service - `downloadAsync` method.

> Maybe someone knows a better way of doing this in Spring?

**Approaches**

- `RestTemplate` which performs `FileCopyUtils.copy(downloadResponse.getBody(), userResponse.getOutputStream());` within `ResponseExtractor`.
- `HttpsURLConnection` which performs `FileCopyUtils.copy(downloadResponse.getBody(), userResponse.getOutputStream());` within controller's return `StreamingResponseBody`

All of the listed approaches do work, they transmit the file content from one server response's `InputStream` to the user's response `OutputStream`. 
However, there is an issue with concurrent downloads (**Spring** stops invoking controller's download method).

**Sources**

*Private info (urls, authentication and etc...) was replaced, code is written strictly for question demonstration purpose*

**Dispatcher**

Constructed by extending `AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer`.

**Controller**

Contains 3 endpoints for different approaches.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/download/way1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void requestDownloadPage(final HttpServletResponse downloadResponse, final HttpServletRequest downloadRequest) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {
         dwn.download(downloadResponse);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/download/way2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public StreamingResponseBody requestDownloadPage2(final HttpServletResponse response) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException {
       return dwn.downloadAsync(response).get();
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/download/way3", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public StreamingResponseBody requestDownloadPage3(final HttpServletResponse response) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, URISyntaxException, IOException {
        return outputStream -> {
            URL url = new URL("https://some/url/path/veryBig.zip");
            HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoOutput(false);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("username:password".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, connection.getHeaderField(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE));
            response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, connection.getHeaderField(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH));
            String disposition = connection.getHeaderField(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION);
            if (disposition != null && !disposition.isEmpty()) {
                response.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, disposition);
            }

            try (InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();) {
                FileCopyUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);

            } catch (Throwable any) {
                // failed
            }
        };
    }
```

**Service**

```
public void download(HttpServletResponse downloadResponse) {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    RequestCallback requestCallback = new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("username:password".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        }
    };

    ResponseExtractor<Void> responseExtractor = response -> {

        List<String> type = response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
        List<String> length = response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH);
        List<String> disposition = response.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION);

        downloadResponse.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, type.get(0));
        downloadResponse.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, length.get(0));
        if (disposition != null && !disposition.isEmpty()) {
            downloadResponse.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, disposition.get(0));
        }

        FileCopyUtils.copy(response.getBody(), downloadResponse.getOutputStream());

        return null;
    };


    restTemplate.execute("https://some/url/path/veryBig.zip",
            HttpMethod.GET,
            requestCallback,
            responseExtractor);
}

@Async
public Future<StreamingResponseBody> downloadAsync(HttpServletResponse response) {
    final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    RequestCallback requestCallback = new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void doWithRequest(ClientHttpRequest request) throws IOException {
            request.getHeaders().set(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString("username:password".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)));
        }
    };

    ResponseExtractor<StreamingResponseBody> responseExtractor = responseOwnCloud -> {

        List<String> type = responseOwnCloud.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE);
        List<String> length = responseOwnCloud.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH);
        List<String> disposition = responseOwnCloud.getHeaders().get(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION);

        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, type.get(0));
        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, length.get(0));
        if (disposition != null && !disposition.isEmpty()) {
            response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, disposition.get(0));
        }

        return outputStream -> {
            FileCopyUtils.copy(responseOwnCloud.getBody(), response.getOutputStream());
        };
    };


    return new AsyncResult<>(restTemplate.execute("https://some/url/path/veryBig.zip",
            HttpMethod.GET,
            requestCallback,
            responseExtractor));

}
```

**Spring Async Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "some.service"})
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {
    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsyncExec-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ed, did you ever sort this out?  I am looking at almost the exact same scenario right now and trying to come up with a good scalable solution.

Comment: If you ever come over here looking for the answer for **Spring 5** instead, you should consider using **WebClient** to request file data and write it down to `HttpServletResponse` using `DataBufferUtils#write` - you can find e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57425230/2004186) how to do it.