# How to read and process partial response from RestClient.exchange as the response contains huge data

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

Have a scenario like where I need to process and check the size of response from below code before returning complete response.

```
ResponseEntity  response = (ResponseEntity) restTemplate.exchange(strRequestURI, HttpMethod.GET, entity, responseClass, mInputParams);
```

Can some one help me here, Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32988370/download-large-file-from-server-using-rest-template-java-spring-mvc

Comment: Thanks Stanis, Can I process the partial response and stop getting data from rest service in case of i don't need any more from response ?